# Enemy is disappearing when patrolling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've made a code for the enemy where it will go left and right and stop at the ledge, but for some reason the enemy will just disappear into thin air, but the enemy can still hit you, when I am going near where the enemy is located.

Here is the code I've made for the Enemy AI:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PatrollingEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed; 
    private bool movingRight = true;
    public Transform groundDetection; //detects the ground if it is there...

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundDetection.position, Vector2.down, 2f);

        if (groundInfo.collider == false)
        {
            if(movingRight == true)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, -200);
                movingRight = false;
            }
            else
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
                movingRight = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link if you want to see how it works with this code: [Link for Bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Q5nsqct9Nk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs because the **z-axis** value of the enemy transform decreases by time until it's less than the **CAMERA z-axis** value and moves outside the camera view.

The main problem is that you set `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, -200);` when the enemy moves to the left direction and when you combine this code with the `transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);`, the enemy moves in its right vector with -200 angle and so after some times, it goes outside the camera view (Because the camera z-index is probably set to -10 by default).

You need to set the local angle of the `y` axis value to **180**:

```cs
...
if (groundInfo.collider == false)
{
    if(movingRight == true)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180); // Change -200 to 180
        movingRight = false;
    }
...
}
...
```

**ANOTHER WAY:** if you want to change the enemy face direction to the left side, you can set `localScale.x` to -1 instead of using rotation.

Here is a simple example:

```cs
// Change face direction to the right when Moving RIGHT
transform.localScale= new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);

// Change face direction to the left when Moving LEFT
transform.localScale= new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
```

Comment: thank you for helping me to solve this problem :D

Comment: @WarlockGames You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it to help others that might have this problem to find the correct answer.